Can a finite dimensional lie algebra have infinitely many ideals
Can a semisimple finite dimensional lie algebra $L$ with zero center have infinitely many ideals ?
It can't have infinitely many non isomorphic ideals by uniqueness of decomposition of semisimple finite dimensional lie algebras into simple ideals, however I am asking about the possibility of containing infinitely many distinct ideals as vector subspaces of $L$

All ideals are build up by some simple ones. So how many combinations are there in finite dimensional case?

Hint: Consider 3-dimensional solvable Lie algebras.

@Tina This shows that there are only finitely many ideals up to isomorphism.

@Moishe Kohan thank you for the comment. It would be great if you have time to elaborate on this as I have very little experience getting my hands dirty with lie algebra computations. Recall that I require my lie algebra to be semisimple

Oh, I did not notice. But semisimple Lie algebra has trivial center and it has only finitely many ideals almost by the definition.

@MoisheKohan it has only finitely many ideals up to isomorphism, but must also finitely many ideals as subspaces ?

These finitely many ideals are not "only up to isomorphism". It are really finitely many. I am sure you will be able to prove that if you fix some ideal decomposition and prove that any ideal is now a direct sub-sum of those. This should be pretty straight forward.

Any semisimple Lie algebra admits a decomposition into simple Lie algebras, so we may assume that our Lie algebra is of the form $L = \bigoplus_{i = 1}^n L_i$ for simple non-abelian Lie algebras $L_i$. We need to check that every ideal of $L$ is given by a subsum of the $L_i$, so that $L$ has exactly $2^n$ ideals.
Suppose that $I$ is an ideal of $L$. Write a given $X \in I$ in terms of its coordinates with respect to the decomposition: $X = (X_1, \dots, X_n)$ with $X_i \in L_i$. If $X_i \in L_i$ is nonzero, then the smallest ideal of $L_i$ containing $X_i$ is $L_i$ itself, since $L_i$ is simple. Equivalently, we have $[L_i, [L_i, [\dots, [L_i, X] \dots ]]] = L_i$ for a sufficiently long chain of brackets, by finite dimensionality and the fact that $Z(L_i) = 0$. This implies that if the projection map $I \hookrightarrow L \to L_i$ is nonzero, then in fact $L_i \subseteq I$, since $[L_i, [L_i, [\dots, [L_i, I]]] = L_i \subseteq I$ because $I$ is an ideal. Hence $I = \bigoplus_{i \in S} L_{i}$, where $S \subseteq \{1, \dots, n\}$ is the set of $i$ for which $I \hookrightarrow L \to L_i$ is nonzero.

Let $L= \bigoplus_{i=1}^n I_i$ be a finite dimensional semisimple lie algebra, $I_i$ simple ideals, $I\subseteq L$ an ideal. This means $I=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n J_i$, for $J_i \subseteq I_i$ subspaces. Since $[I_i, I_j] \subseteq I_i \cap I_j =\{0\}$, for $i\neq j$, and $L$ semisimple, we get for any $j\in J_k$:
$$j=[\sum_i x_i,\sum_j y_j]= \sum_{i,j} [x_i,y_j]=\sum_i [x_i,y_i]$$, for some $x_i \in I_i, y_i \in j_i$. Since $[x_i,y_i]\in I_i$ and the sum of $I_i$ is direct we get that: $ j =[x_k,y_k]\in [L,J_k]$. This implies $$[L,J_k]=J_k$$
And the simplicity of $I_i$ gives us:
$$\forall i\in \{1, \dots, n\}: J_i \in \{I_i, \{0\} \}$$
It follows that any Ideal is the sum of some $I_{i}$.

Thanks for your answer. I don't see why "This means ..." In the third line of your answer

@Amr This can be proven similarly: pick a $y\in I$, find $x\in L, z\in I$, s.t.: $\sum y_i =y =[x,z] =\sum [x_i, z_i]$, and get the "coefficients" $y_i=[x_i,z]\in I$.
